# Reference got from mutex'a value doesn't live enought

Tags: multithreading, rust, mutex, lifetime, egui

I'm learning Rust and trying to create a Admin panel like with egui and multi-threading;
One thread which update the Student struct in an Hashmap && another which run egui and display Student information;
here the problem, I have:

```rust
students: Arc<Hashmap<PathBuf, Mutex<Student>>>
actual_student : Option<Mutex<Student>>
// The student in the popup
```

```rust
// Here when I would like to get the &Student after clicking on a button 'See more'
self.actual_student = Some(self.students.get(path.deref()).unwrap());
// But got the error: lifetime may not live enough assignment requires that `'1` must outlive `'a`
```

Here the complete code of the implementation:

```rust
pub struct Maestro<'a> {
    pub students: Arc<HashMap<PathBuf, Mutex<Student>>>,
    pub logger: Logger,
    pub actual_student: Option<&'a Mutex<Student>>,
    // Would like to make like this: pub student: Option<&Student> but cannot get reference to
    // Student from mutex's value
}

impl<'a> Maestro<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let config = load_config();
        let watcher = config.watcher;
        let students = Arc::new(watcher.init());
        let mut students_for_thread = Arc::clone(&students);
        std::thread::spawn(move || {
            watcher.run(&mut students_for_thread);
        });
        Maestro {
            students,
            logger: config.logger,
            actual_student: None,
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> eframe::App for Maestro<'a> {
    fn update(&mut self, ctx: &egui::Context, _frame: &mut eframe::Frame) {
        egui::CentralPanel::default().show(ctx, |ui| {
            for (path, student) in self.students.iter() {
                if let Ok(mutex) = student.try_lock() {
                    ui.horizontal(|ui| {
                        ui.label(&mutex.name);
                        match &mutex.bashrc_editable {
                            true => ui.colored_label(egui::Color32::GREEN, "true"),
                            false => ui.colored_label(egui::Color32::RED, "false"),
                        };
                        if ui.button("See more").clicked() {
                            if self.students.contains_key(path) {
                                self.actual_student = Some(self.students.get(path.deref()).unwrap());
                                // FIXME 10/27/22 ectaclick: lifetime may not live long enough assignment requires that `'1` must outlive `'a`
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        // Would like to create a 'popup' on the right of the list
        if self.actual_student.is_some() {
            let student = self.actual_student.unwrap().lock().unwrap();
            egui::SidePanel::right("student").show(ctx, |ui| {
                ui.label(student.name.as_str());
                match student.bashrc_editable {
                    true => ui.colored_label(Color32::GREEN, "true"),
                    false => ui.colored_label(Color32::RED, "false"),
                }
            });
        }
        std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));
    }
```

I tried to many type of `actual_student`:

```rust
Option<Student>
Box<Student>
Option<&Student>
```

Tried to clone the value but the `actual_student` is not the same of the `Student` in the `Hashmap` which is the `Student` struct updated by the second thread.

But the problem is still the same.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct). Does `actual_student` really need to be a member of `Maestro`?

Comment: In my opinion he should, `Maestro` is the stuct which update my UI, maybe i can store the `pathBuf` instead of the struct and get the student from the stored `pathBuf` when i need it. I saw that i can use `RwLock` instead of `Mutex`. I haven't see a project which implement what i want to do, so i canno't see how it should be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the lifetime error because if the value is removed the hashmap, the the reference you have in actual_student becomes invalid.

A direct solution to this is to use
`Arc<Mutex<Student>>` instead of `Mutex<Student>`

And the use simply use clone of the Arc object, this is relatively lightweight as it is not copying the whole object.

But in general, you're trying to think in OOP. a better approach is to use an id, for example:

```
actual_student_id : Option<u64>
```

which means you'll have to use

```
students.iter().find(|it|it.id == actual_student_id)
```

everytime you want to get a reference to actual student, but that avoids using Arc, and will probably get rid of Mutex too which is even better as mutexes are generally a source of performance hit, sometimes hard to debug.